# CSS: Absolute Element inside Absolute Element

Tags: html, css

I'm studying CSS and as I learn, when an absolute element A inside relative element B, that A will be relative to B. I want to test the case absolute element inside absolute element but I don't see any differences.

Here is my test:

```
<div id="box-1">
    <div id="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

Absolute inside Relative

```
#box-1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000000;
    position: relative;
}

#box-2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Absolute inside Absolute

```
#box-1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000000;
    position: absolute;
}

#box-2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    position: absolute;
}
```

So. my question is: Are there any differences when an absolute element is inside other absolute element ? If not, why every examples that I have read always just mention the case absolute element inside other relative element ?

thanks :)

Comment: you can test it yourself, here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jj3dbfha/1/ it looks like it behaves the same as absolute in relative

Comment: @AbdulAhmad No. my question is different. Did you  read that post ?

Comment: @When someone downvote, please give reason ?

Comment: `first` I didn't down vote - `second` its not different, you asked basically the same question - `third` if you don't see any difference it must be similar, see the fiddle I posted.

Comment: As far as my knowledge about this, if we want to set a position of an element using `absolute` we must make a parent as `relative` because the child will use it's relative parent as its origin and its position is set relative to this parent not relative browser's width/hight. an `absolute` within `absolute` is always use the window area as parent so they with positioned  themselves relative to window

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Positioning an `absolute` element in relation to an `absolute` parent is "absolutely" the same as with a `relative` parent. In fact it's also the same if the parent were `fixed`.

Basically you will always position an `absolute` element in relation with the closest parent with **NO** `position:static` (which is the position of all elements by default).

While learning the example most common is `absolute` inside `relative` because while you are making some basic html, the first element you need to be `absolute` won't be positioned (probably) as you wish till you set `relative` to the parent and that won't change the position of this parent at all (from `static` to `relative` shoudn't make any difference on any element).

Probably your next question you may find willing to do is "why not all the elements are set to `position:relative` by default if it won't change the flow of the html at all and then you save time not adding `position:relative` to so many classes?". Yes, I coudn't understand it either till some day I needed an `absolute` element to be positioned in relation to NOT the closest parent. (for example, a position of an `absolute` submenu on relation to the main-menu `ul` but not to his direct parent which would be a `li`). Hope it's clear enough

Comment: thanks for your answer. Many things make me clear now :)